# Failed to link openssl to Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, openssl

I have started a project with Qtcreator on linux. This project uses the Openssl library to work.
So In my .pro file I have added theses lines :

```
LIBS    += -lssl
LIBS    += -lcrypto
```

So on linux it works perfectly.

But, I have to continue my project on windows. I had to install Openssl with cygwin, I have chosen this package : "cygwin32-openssl-1.0.1e-1.tar.bz2" because I compile in 32bits.

I have created a sub-repertory, named libs, in my program folder and I put the three openssl folders (bin, include and lib) in my "libs" repertory.

The content of the lib directory is :

```
libcrypto.a
libcrypto.dll.a
libssl.a
libssl.dll.a
pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
pkgconfig/libssl.pc
pkgconfig/openssl.pc
```

In the bin directory I have 2 .dll, cygcrypto-1.0.0.dll and cygssl-1.0.0.dll

I added in my .pro file these lines :

```
LIBS    += -lssl
LIBS    += -lcrypto
LIBS    += -L"$$PWD/libs/openssl/lib/"
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs/openssl/include/
```

If I change -L"$$PWD/libs/openssl/lib/" by -L"$$PWD/libs/openssl/bin/", the compilator don't recognized the -lssl and -lcrypto options.

QtCreator recognized the headers files (for example ) and when I compile, no error occurred.

But when I launch my program, it doesn't work and no error appears.
So I put a breaking point at the begining of my main function, and I re-launch the program. After that a little window indicates to me this error :

> Executable failed: During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135

I use Qt 5.4.0 and Mingw 32bits

I don't undertsand why it doesn't work. Can you help me please ?
Thank you.

Comment: To make this question answerable without guessing, you need to let us know: 1. Exactly what Qt you are using - provide the download link to the file you've installed. 2. What compiler you're using to build your project. **Do not answer in comments. Edit the question to provide missing information. Do not indicate edits with words "Edited" etc. SO tracks all edits, so you don't have to.**

Answer (score 0):

The entirety of your project needs to use cygwin, or none of it. Since I assume you're compiling using a Visual Studio compiler, you'll need to use an OpenSSL build that isn't cygwin-dependent. For example, the one from [Shining Light Productions](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), the de-fact OpenSSL binary purveyor for Windows.

Comment: I have download Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.2d ans I have installed it. I have also change theses lines in my .pro file :
`LIBS    += -llibeay32
LIBS    += -L"D:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/"`

But when I compile and launch my program I have an error :
this application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
please contact the application's support team for more information.

And this error message in QtCreator :
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.

I use Qt 5.4.0 and mingw 32bits